# Header is geting hidden when selected a value from dropdown

Tags: jquery

From the dropdown when i select a status , i am finding the header missing .

Could you please let me know how to fix this ??

This is my code

```
$(document).on('change', 'select#filterstatus', function(event) {
    $(".AddreqTableCols").hide();
    $(".label_p:contains('" + $(this).val() + "')").closest(".AddreqTableCols").show();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cdkLkcdk/16/

Coulf you please let me know how to fix this ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a selector `.AddreqTableCols` that mathces both the content rows as well as the header one.

Be more specific by targeting the `.AddreqTableCols` elements in the `.divTableContent` div only.

```
$(document).on('change', 'select#filterstatus', function(event) {
    $(".divTableContent .AddreqTableCols").hide();
    $(".label_p:contains('" + $(this).val() + "')").closest(".AddreqTableCols").show();
});
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/cdkLkcdk/17/